# Python mock.patch() not mocking imported class module

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a some code that looks like this (abridged):

```
## ./module_1/lambda_function.py

from shared.graphql_helpers import GraphQLClient

gql_client = GraphQLClient('http://host_url.test/')

post_event_to_consumer(event):
   response = gql_client.make_query(mutation, { 'data': event, {})

lambda_hanbdler(event, context):
   post_event_to_consumer(event['detail']
```

The module imported is such:

```
## ./shared/graphql_helpers.py

import requests

class GraphQLClient:
    def __init__(self, url):
      self.host_url = url

    def make_query(self, query, variables, headers):
        request = requests.post(self.host_url, json={'query': query, 'variables': variables}, headers=headers)
        if request.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception()
        elif request.json()['errors']:
            raise Exception()
        else:
            return request.json()['data']
```

The project structure is such:

```
module_1
    __init__.py
    lambda_function.py
    lambda_function_test.py
shared
    __init__.py
    graphql_helpers.py
```

My problem is that I am trying to patch `GraphQLClient` in `lambda_function_test.py` but it does not seem to be working.

My unit test looks like this:

```
## ./module_1/lambda_function_test.py

import os
from unittest import mock, TestCase

class TestLambdaFunction(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('module_1.lambda_function.GraphQLClient')
    def test_post_event_to_compplex(self, mock_gql_client):
        mock_gql_client = mock.Mock()
        mock_gql_client.make_query.return_value = {}

        result = post_event_to_consumer(json_data['detail'])

        assert result == None
```

From what I read online, `patch` mocks the import in the SUT's namespace, however, when I run the test, it imports the original GraphQLClient and throws a ConnectionError. I also tried removing `module_1` from the path but that didn't work either.

Not sure what's incorrect here, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You only need to mock the object which has been used in your main code for which you have written test for. so in this case try mocking GraphQLClient directly using @mock.patch('GraphQLClient')

Comment: Another issue might be that you're instantiating the (original) `GraphQLClient` at the module-level, which means that code runs at the time of import, and only _after_ that will it be replaced with the mock object. Much cleaner to have the `gql_client` as a parameter to your various functions, not as a module-level global.

Comment: @VMSMani I had tried that but that's an invalid path for patch.

@Lagerbaer Yeah, that's what I was considering - I'm new to Python unit testing and method injection seemed like the easiest way through, but it seemed like all the references I found online use `mock.patch()` so still trying to pin what's going wrong here.